# Python - Finding each occurrence of a value in a mixed array (integers, lists)

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop

I have an array: `x = [ [1, 2], 1, 1, [2, 1, [1, 2]] ]`
in which I want to count every occurrence of the number `1`, and store that number in the variable `one_counter`. `x.count(1)` returns only 2 occurrences of `1`, which is insufficient. 
My code below serves my purpose and stores `5` in `one_counter`, however it looks messy and feels unpythonic to me.
Any suggestions how I can improve its pythonicity and expand it into more-dimensional lists? 
Thanks!

```
x = [[1, 2], 1, 1, [2, 1, [1, 2]]]

one_counter = 0

for i in x:
    if type(i) == list:
        for j in i:
            if type(j) == list:
                for k in j:
                    if k == 1:
                        one_counter += 1

            else:
                if j == 1:
                    one_counter += 1

    else:
        if i == 1:
            one_counter += 1
```

Comment: What does scale have to do with this?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I guess he overused the word Scale,he might have meant expansion of his datatype into more dimensional lists.

Comment: @DhruvPathak Yes, sir! I misunderstood that for scale.

Comment: So how did you end up with this list, and why do you need this count? The whole thing seems oddly artificial.

Comment: @Karl Would you be upset if I said it was me practicing, hitting a road block, and asking for help?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use recursion:

```
def flatten_count(iterable, element):
    count = 0
    for item in iterable:
        if item == element:
            count += 1
        if isinstance(item, list):
            count += flatten_count(item, element)
    return count
```

Or more concisely:

```
def flatten_count(iterable, element):
    return sum(
        flatten_count(item, element) if isinstance(item, list) else item == element
        for item in iterable 
    )
```

Use like this:

```
>>> x = [[1, 2], 1, 1, [2, 1, [1, 2]]]
>>> print(flatten_count(x, 1))
5
```

Comment: Thanks so much, Mark! That makes perfect sense, and now I understand recursion better along with the handiness that is isinstance().

Answer (score 3):

A hacky solution, working by conversion of datatype to string :
http://codepad.org/vNEv6B8M

```
import re
x = [ [1, 2], 1, 1, [2, 1, [1, 2]] ]
nums = [int(i) for i in re.findall(r'\d+', str(x))]
print(nums.count(1))
```

Answer (score 2):

I think it's better to separate this task into 2 parts.

## Part 1

Part 1 is to create an generator which will flatten the input list.

```
def flatten_list(L):
    for i in L:
        if isinstance(i,list):
            for j in flatten_list(i):
                yield j
        else:
            yield i
```

Testing the output:

```
x = [[1, 2], 1, 1, [2, 1, [1, 2]]]

for i in flatten_list(x):
    print i
```

Output:

```
1
2
1
1
2
1
1
2
```

## Part 2

Part 2 is to use the flattened list to count the number of occurrences of `1` in it:

```
print(sum(i==1 for i in flatten_list(x)))
```

Output:

```
5
```

Note that `i==1` returns `True` if `i=1`, and `False` if `i` is not equal to `1`. But `True`is equal to `1` and `False` is equal to `0`, so `sum` just calculates the number of `True` occurrences (which is equal to `5` in this case).

Comment: Thanks for breaking it down. I really appreciate it.